# SE Podcasts - wrong and dead link, strange filenames, missing date in filenames

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, broken-link, podcast

At https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/page/7/ there's the link to the SE Podcast #01 titled [Stack Exchange Podcast – Episode #88](http://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-podcast-episode-88) which is

1. wrong as this is the first episode of new SE Podcast series
2. dead (Oops, looks like we can't find that page!)

Also what does number "7" do in the link to the SE Podcast #02 - http://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-podcast-7/s-Fk90d ?

Additionaly

1. the name of mp3 file for SE Podcast #01 is `Edited Podcast - 192 MP3` and for SE Podcast #02 is `2011-04-26 - Edited - MP3 VBR 3.mp3`. They are not in line with the rest of the series.
2. names of some mp3 files (e.g., of podcasts #08, #09, #10, #11) instead of date of the podcast have some meaningless (internal?) terms like *Publish* or *Rendered*.

What a mess...

Comment: Verified dead link :)

Answer (score 5):

The links should be fixed.

The bizarre names are subtle insights into the history of the podcast. I won't spoil *all* the surprises for you, but SO Podcast #88 *was* SE Podcast #01 - the decision to renumber was made during / after that episode.

I recommend finding a good bit of software to handle downloading and listening to them. Podcast feeds were sorta *designed* for that...